# How can I adjust that when I write: paper and the bot then writes: scissors, it says either "win" or "lose"

Tags: c#

Im new in c# & thats one of my first games, so sorry for that maybe bad written code.
Note: Please dont leak the full solution of that game. Just the solution of that situation. I wanna resolve it from myself. (Sry for my bad english)

```
        {
            string[] list = { "Scissors", "Paper", "Rock" };
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int index = rnd.Next(list.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Do you wanna play Scissors, Paper, Rock? Type 'y' for Yes and 'n' for No");
            string output = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (output == "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scissors, Paper or Rock?");
                string abfrage = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                if (abfrage == "Scissor" || abfrage == "Paper" || abfrage == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(list[index]);
                    string convert = Convert.ToString(list[index]);
                    if (convert == abfrage)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Draw");
                    }
                    if (convert != abfrage) // Here is the problem
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Win");
                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the actual winning condition, not just the equality

```
if (convert == abfrage) {
    Console.WriteLine("Draw");
    return;
} 
if (abfrage == "Scissor") {
    if (convert == "Paper") {
        Console.WriteLine("Win");
    } else if (convert == "Rock") {
        Console.WriteLine("Lose");
    }
}
// repeat for other cases
```